# Connecting to Windows Guest using Headless Virtualbox / phpvirtualbox and an OpenVPN-Server

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, vpn, openvpn

this is the basic setup I'm trying to achieve:

Windows 7 Office PC - connected to OpenVPN-Server of Ubuntu Host, Remotedesktop/Browser to connect to the Windows Server running on the headless Virtualbox on the Ubuntuhost.

I used this tutorial to install the headless Virtualbox / phpvirtualbox https://www.ostechnix.com/install-oracle-virtualbox-ubuntu-16-04-headless-server/

and this for setting up the OpenVPN-server
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-16-04

I switched the network adapter type to NAT from bridged, now the guest is at least connected to the Internet.

I want to connect to the OpenVPN-Server and be able to open a webpage hosted by the guest (guests-vpn-ip):8001 and remote desktop, which would be port 3389. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did resolve this by getting my virtual machines virtual IP address via web console (you can do this on command line aswell) and then added port forwarding from the virtual ip to the real ip. piece of cake when you know what needs to be done!